# How to extract json format column into individual columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a json formatted column in a csv file.. there are 3 rows and data looks like

```
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'AAA', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901,'ID': 2, 'Name': 'XYZ', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901}]
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'BBB', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901,'ID': 2, 'Name': 'DDD', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901}]
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'CCC', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901,'ID': 2, 'Name': 'XYZ', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901,'ID': 3, 'Name': 'MMM', 'type': 'ACCOUNT', 'Date': 19980901}]
```

I have to split these row to look like below format.

```
ID  Name   type      Date
1   AAA    ACCOUNT   19980901
2   XYZ    ACCOUNT   19980901
1   BBB    ACCOUNT   19980901
2   DDD    ACCOUNT   19980901
1   CCC    ACCOUNT   19980901
2   XYZ    ACCOUNT   19980901
3   MMM    ACCOUNT   19980901
```

I am trying with below code but not getting output.

```
date=20220321
txt = Path(fpath+"file.csv").read_text()
txt = txt.replace('"{','{').replace('}"', '}').replace('""', '"')
df = pd.read_json(txt, lines=True)
filename="file"+ date + "_02.csv"
df.to_csv(fpath+filename)
```

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to use the `pd.read_json(txt, lines=True)` the text has to be in a very specific format. Basically, every line needs to be a valid JSON object.

You will have to first replace single quotes with double quotes and remove the square brackets.

#### Code

```
from pathlib import Path

txt = Path('./data/data.json').read_text()
txt = txt.replace('\'' , '"').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

The contents of `txt` variable is:

```
{"ID": 1, "Name": "AAA", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901,"ID": 2, "Name": "XYZ", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901}
{"ID": 1, "Name": "BBB", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901,"ID": 2, "Name": "DDD", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901}
{"ID": 1, "Name": "CCC", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901,"ID": 2, "Name": "XYZ", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901,"ID": 3, "Name": "MMM", "type": "ACCOUNT", "Date": 19980901}
```

Now you can use `pd.read_json()` as follows to get the desired output

```
df = pd.read_json(txt, lines=True)
df
```

#### Output

[image]